# android command not found on my MAC terminal

Tags: android, macos, terminal, android-sdk-tools

I have installed the android sdk in my mac machine and it is at /Users/chaluwa/android-sdks, so I set the $PATH variable to include the tools and platform-tools sub-folders from where android sdk is installed. echo $PATH confirms that my $PATH includes the android sdk locations but executing the android command from a terminal says : -bash: android: command not found

If I navigate to /Users/chaluwa/android-sdks/tools and type android command, I get the same -bash: android: command not found error, however typing ./android from the same location works.

I need to be able to issue the android command from anywhere in the terminal, how do I fix these issues. Pls see - http://ur1.ca/ikxqw

Comment: Apparently it is not in your path.  You may have to log out and back in for changes to take effect. Note that unlike on windows the current directory is not traditionally part of the search path on a unix derived platform, due to its multiuser origins.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but logging out and back in did not make any difference. I still have  : -bash: android: command not found